# Rails: Cookieoverflow. When does Rails use cookies without letting me know?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, overflow

without posting my exact problem with a Cookieoverflow, I want to ask, what can cause a CookieOverflow?

I have only one session-var `session[:user] = @user`, which is the current logged in account.

In my whole app I have no problems with a CookieOverflow, but in one action, where I am not using the session- or cookies-var, I get a CookieOverflow.

So without inspecting my problem in detail, what can cause a CookieOverflow as well, when it is not the false use of `session[]` and `cookies[]`?

I really don't think that this session-var for the user is really the problem... I commented it out and still get the error.

So the question is exactly, "In what cases does Rails use cookies, without my explicit call of it? / When does Rails use cookies, wihtout letting me know of it?"

Yours,

Joern

Comment: Probably your serialized `@user` is to big for the cookie. Try switching to a different session storage (DB or filesystem). Or put only the `@user.id` into the cookie.

Comment: Also see section 2.4 of the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions

Comment: Is your cookie growing to over 4KB? That's the size limit for a cookie I believe. You don't have to store a whole model in the session, and I think it's generally not recommended. Try storing `@user.id` instead and see if that mitigates the problem.

Comment: As for the question when Rails sets cookies without your knowledge, the answer is: only if you use session. You may check in your browser which cookies are stored for your application. If you use something like the 'LiveHTTPHeaders' plugin (this one is for Firefox), you may see what cookies are being set by your application in each request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@user is an instance of a User model, I assume?

A quick google search suggests storing models in cookies is a bad idea:
http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails#slimitations

The session cookie size is pretty small (~4kb), could it be that the @user instance is bigger than that?  Perhaps you could just store @user.id in the session?

Also, the error may appear when you are making changes to the object referenced by @user elsewhere in the model; if the session cookie is tracking this object, then that could push it over the 4kb limit.

Just some thoughts - happy to be corrected by Those Of Great Reputation.

Comment: I really don't think that this session-var for the user is really the problem... I commented it out and still get the error. So the question is exactly, "In what cases does Rails use cookies, without my explicit call of it / when does Rails use cookies, wihtout letting me know of it"

Comment: Did you clear try clearing out your cookies after you commented out the use of the session-var? Re: the question of when Rails uses cookies with your explicit call of it, I'm not familiar with any time when this could happen.

Comment: BTW, Here's a very similar problem another Rubyist had storing @user in a cookie: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/167761.  It might be worth being 100% sure this isn't the cause. Sorry I can't help you out any further: good luck.

Answer (score 3):

you cant store more than 4k data in cookies.i think your @user variables size is more than 4k.that's why error is raised